# Wordpress Bad Request Error

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

Hey guys,
I've seen a few people bring it up but haven't found a solution yet.

Every link I click on from the home page goes to a blank page with the text, "Bad Request."

Nothing else. No errors, nothing. Even if I copy the permalink right from the Wordpress page area, it gives me the error. To see what I mean, try this - http://3mpromos.ca/carcrazy/your-projects/

The home page is http://3mpromos.ca/carcrazy/. The links on there should go to the 'Venues' page, but keep giving me an error. The only links that work are to the signup and login areas.

Any ideas?

Comment: Even my default post doesn't work - http://3mpromos.ca/carcrazy/hello-world/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Getting IIS6 to play nice with WordPress Pretty Permalinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113489/getting-iis6-to-play-nice-with-wordpress-pretty-permalinks)

Search for "iis" here:

- [Using Permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)

Comment: Yea apparently pretty URLs don't work because ISS doesn't use mod_rewrite. There are some workarounds that I found through that link, but I don't have the time to implement them.

Answer (score 0):

You are running the site on IIS, that causes the problem ... I mean I'm not an expert of IIS but from the HTTP headers I can see that for the next URL

http://3mpromos.ca/carcrazy/index.php

the headers are

```
Server  Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.2.3, ASP.NET
```

And for this:

http://3mpromos.ca/carcrazy/index.php/omgloller

I get these headers

```
Server  Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
```

So I suppose for the second request IIS doesn't trigger the PHP module. So you might want to setup IIS to handle URL rewrites. I can't help more, Google is your friend or try to create a new question with IIS specific tags.

Comment: Thanks, I really didn't even have a lead before that.
It's weird though, because this site - http://3mpromos.ca/automotive/ - which I haven't touched, works just fine and is hosted in the same place.